# Block Duplicate Questions

Tags: feature-request

At the time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410972 was posted, the active revision of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27408354 (#2) contained the *exact same body text* (verified by inspection and MD5).

The system should detect and block when a user tries to post a question with the exact same body text as one of their previous questions so that the community doesn't have to spend time noticing and handling the dupe.

Comment: In addition, it would be nice if some helpful comments were provided to the offending user, so they can understand why we don't allow double-posting

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Similar situation, but I don't think it's a duplicate. That appears to be talking about questions that are merely similar, whereas in this case the text is *exactly* the same.

Comment: That question talks about similar questions that would be exact duplicates if not for SO automatically blocking them.  I don't know why your example wasn't blocked, but your feature request (block exact duplicates) was confirmed by Shog in that question's comments to be already implemented.

Comment: You can't even flag/close them as dupes (at least not with the standard process) unless one of them has an upvoted answer.

Comment: I think it was the fact that the post-edit content was what was duplicated here that caused the duplicate-post question blocking to fail. I think I've seen that maybe twice in my entire time here, so I'm not sure if this is an edge case even worth the effort to check against.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: You can vote to close questions by the same user as dupes regardless of their having an answer.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Good to know. I thought I had tried and failed to do that in the past. But my memory might be fuzzy, and it was almost identical questions by different users in that case.

Comment: Yes, [a duo of buddies (or one person with two accounts) can circumvent duplicate closures](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171371).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom By "the obvious technical measure is already implemented" I think he just means that the system already has a way to do this because it auto-flags posts when users post exact-copy answers to multiple questions. Afaik, there's currently nothing that compares question bodies though.

Comment: @animuson: The original revision requested "the obvious technical measure" (blocking exact duplicates) and Shog said it was already implemented, so I take that to mean blocking questions is implemented.